# numpy / pandas array comparison with multiple values in other array

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have an array

```
a = np.arange(0, 100)
```

and another array with some cut-off points

```
b = np.array([5, 8, 15, 35, 76])
```

I want to create an array such that

```
c = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ..., 4, 4, 5]
```

Is there an elegant / fast way to do this? Possible in Pandas?

Comment: does `c` start with 4 zeros or 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a compact way -

```
(a[:,None]>=b).sum(1)
```

Another with `cumsum` -

```
p = np.zeros(len(a),dtype=int)
p[b] = 1
out = p.cumsum()
```

Another with `searchsorted` -

```
np.searchsorted(b,a,'right')
```

Another with `repeat` -

```
np.repeat(range(len(b)+1),np.ediff1d(b,to_begin=b[0],to_end=len(a)-b[-1]))
```

Another with `isin` and `cumsum` -

```
np.isin(a,b).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way `cut`

```
pd.cut(a,[-np.Inf]+b.tolist()+[np.Inf]).codes
Out[383]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], dtype=int8)
```